# Programmatically attach JsonSubType to JsonType

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I have the following interface with a "type" JsonType and 2 subtypes associated with this. I have one more subtype to attach to this JsonType which cannot be added here. Is it possible to attach a subtype programmatically to this object from a different class altogether?

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", defaultImpl = DefaultAnimalSpec.class)
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "mammal", value = Elephant.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "reptile", value = Snake.class),
})
public interface AnimalSpec { }
```

I attempted using the ObjectMapper approach as follows, but I'm not able to figure out how would it be attached to the parent JsonType:

```
final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new DefaultObjectMapper();
jsonMapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(Fish.class, "aqua"));
```

Any thoughts?